# Create all combination of IPL cricket teams with validation criteria

Tags: python, algorithm, combinatorics

So, I place bets on Dream11 app. In the app, you have to select your team of 11 out of playing 22 players. It has some constraints on a valid team.

Constraints(eg. CSK vs. MI):

Number of wicket keepers can be from 1 to 4

Number of batsmen can be from 3 to 6

Number of allrounders can be from 1 to 4

Number of bowlers can be from 3 to 6

Number of players selected from CSK should be less than equal to 7

Number of players selected from MI should be less than equal to 7

Sum Credits of all the selected players should be less than equal to 100

Now the thing is that sometimes creating these team becomes a really difficult task when they release the lineups and a lot of players you selected are not playing or when one of the playing team is way stronger than other. So, I thought of making a program in which I can input the playing 22 and I can get all the valid teams of 11 players that I can make.

Here is the input file format:

(The first line is just for reference, it's not there in the original file. Every column is tab-separated because it is easy to copy-paste from Excel that way.)

---

```
#Name   #Credit   #Team1   #Team2   #WK   #BAT   #ALL   #BOWL   #Sel
Glenn Maxwell   8.5 1   0   0   0   1   0   0
Chris Woakes    9   0   1   0   0   1   0   0
Mitchell Marsh  8   1   0   0   0   1   0   0
Marcus Stoinis  8.5 1   0   0   0   1   0   0
Jonny Bairstow  9.5 0   1   1   0   0   0   0
Jos Buttler 9.5 0   1   1   0   0   0   0
Alex Carey  8.5 1   0   1   0   0   0   0
Eoin Morgan 9   0   1   0   1   0   0   0
Sam Billings    8   0   1   0   1   0   0   0
Joe Root    10  0   1   0   1   0   0   0
David Warner    10  1   0   0   1   0   0   0
Aaron Finch 9.5 1   0   0   1   0   0   0
Marnus Labuschagne  8.5 1   0   0   1   0   0   0
Jason Roy   9   0   1   0   1   0   0   0
Jofra Archer    9   0   1   0   0   0   1   0
Tom Curran  8.5 0   1   0   0   0   1   0
Adil Rashid 9   0   1   0   0   0   1   0
Mark Wood   8.5 0   1   0   0   0   1   0
Josh Hazlewood  8.5 1   0   0   0   0   1   0
Mitchell Starc  9   1   0   0   0   0   1   0
Pat Cummins 9   1   0   0   0   0   1   0
Adam Zampa  8.5 1   0   0   0   0   1   0
```

The Credit column has credit for the respective player. In all other columns, 0 represents that the respective player is not that thing and 1 represents that the respective player is that thing(eg. 1 in Team1 column represents that player is in Actual Playing Team 1 and 1 in the WK column represents that player is wicket-keeper.)

Here is what I programmed to do this task.

```
import itertools
ValidTeam = []
with open("Players.txt", "r") as dfile:
    players = [t for t in dfile.read().split("\n")]
combos = list(itertools.combinations(players, 11))
for combo in combos:
    crd, t1, t2, wk, bat, alr, bowl = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
    for tplayer in combo:
        player = tplayer.split("\t")
        crd += float(player[1])
        t1 += int(player[2])
        t2 += int(player[3])
        wk += int(player[4])
        bat += int(player[5])
        alr += int(player[6])
        bowl += int(player[7])
    if crd <= 100 and t1 <= 7 and t2 <= 7 and (wk in range(1,5)) and (bat in range(3,7)) and (alr in range(1,5)) and (bowl in range(3,7)):
        ValidTeam.append(combo)
        print(player)
    print("")
print(ValidTeam)
```

Now the problem is for some reason that I don't understand it is showing this error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\RACHIT\Desktop\TM.py", line 12, in <module>
    crd += float(player[1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Please, help me out with this problem.
Also, since there will be 22C11 possible teams and for the future, chosen captains and vice-captains have special privileges so that makes it 2! * 22C11, plus the validation part of that many teams, plus I'm thinking of processing those valid teams too in future to choose the best out of them, so it can take a lot of time to process. So ideas to make it faster, efficient and better will be much appreciated and welcomed.

PS: I'm using itertools for the first time so don't have much idea about it but it so really convenient.

Comment: Don't copy paste from excel to create a csv, save it to a csv from the excel with a delimeter or best read excel directly using existing python modules. Use appropriate modules like csv or pandas to read the csv. If you choose a delimeter which is already present in the file the excel application should take care of appropriately escaping the characters following [standards](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180) of a csv file. A simple copy paste will not ensure the escaping of characters, making it unable to parse again.

Comment: My guess, there might be a blank line in your input file. The error suggest that the size of list after split is smaller than 2.

Comment: @Suparshva Thanks man, It turns out when I copy-pasted, it took one extra "next line" at the end. It's running now but validating 22C11 teams is taking lot of time. Any suggestion to improve on that?

Comment: @Suparshva Also, not thinking of taking data directly from CSV or Excel playing 22 is fixed only after the lineup is out, so it's faster if I delete the non-playing player rows manually and copy-paste in a txt.

Answer (score 1):

**Scope for improvements:**

1. `players = [t.split('\t') for t in dfile.read().split("\n")]`

   String operations are expensive. Instead of doing it later after generating combinations, do it before. This way you will only do it once for all players.
2. You can process combos in parallel. Convert your inner loop to a function that processes a list. Use pool.map.

**Example implementation:**

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def fun(combo):
    # Implement your logic here for one team, similar to your logic inside current for loop
    # return True if valid else if invalid return False 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    .
    .  # Implement reading players from file and generating list of combinations
    .

    num_workers = mp.cpu_count()
    with mp.Pool(num_workers) as pool:
        valid_teams = [c for c, keep in zip(combos, pool.map(fun, combos)) if keep]

    # do something with valid_teams
```

**Reference:** https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. Haven't ever done parallel processing. Will look into the documentation but it'll be a lot easier for me if you could explain me how to implement it. If it's a lot to explain then leave it, I'll look into it anyway. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Added an example implementation structure.

Answer (score 0):

`list index out of range` implies that you are trying to access an array index which does not exist,

player[1] assumes that the player array formed in `tplayer.split("\t")` has at least 2 elements. the split has not resulted in such an array, fixing that should help

Comment: When I tried to print out only `player` after commenting out all these summation operations, it is showing that the list is forming just right.